# Display custom icon image [html] on each xAxis category label with highcharts.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have this chart graph I am working on, basically is a set of 10 rows [series], I have to dinamically add a custom Icon (image) to the start of each bar, I am able to ad an image but is displaying the same mew element on all the rows, would really appreciate any help on this.

Here is a jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/KrTbz/ I created.

and this is the js code I need to make work

```
            labels: {
                color: '#fff',

                x: 5,
                useHTML: true,
                formatter: function () {
                    return '<img class="" src="http://dummyimage.com/60x60/ff6600/ffffff"/>';
                }

            }
```

Hope I can get some help.

Comment: I see you already are placing DummyImage http://dummyimage.com/60x60/ff6600/ffffff in front of all of them.

Do you just want to vary that?

Comment: That is the problem, I need to place a different icon img on each bar, any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See http://jsfiddle.net/troynt/KrTbz/3/

Just replace the random word placeholders with whatever images you want.

```
formatter: function () {
    return {
        'Awesome': 'blah',
        'Awesome Previous': 'yadda',
        'Good': 'dabba',
        'Good Previous': 'doo',
        'Okay': 'word',
        'Okay Previous':'up',
        'Awful': 'blah',
        'Awfull Previous': 'blah2'
    }[this.value];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To apply custom image per label, try this, using an array of images with label as index:

```
 $(function () {

        var categoryImgs = {
            'Apples': '<img src="http://dummyimage.com/60x60/ff6600/ffffff"><img>&nbsp;',
            'Oranges':'<img src="http://highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png"><img>&nbsp;',
            'Pears':'<img src="http://highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png"><img>&nbsp;',
            'Grapes':'<img src="http://highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png"><img>&nbsp;',
            'Bananas':'<img src="http://highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png"><img>&nbsp;'
        };

        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },

            title: {
                text: 'Stacked column chart'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas'],
                labels: {
                    x: 5,
                    useHTML: true,                        
                    formatter: function () {
                        return '<div class="myToolTip" title="Hello ' 
                       + this.value +'">' +  categoryImgs[this.value] + '</div>';
                    },
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can start by trying this:

http://jsfiddle.net/KrTbz/1/

```
formatter: function () {
                    console.log(this);
                    return '<img class="" ' +
src="http://dummyimage.com/100x30/ff6600/ffffff?text=' + this.value + '" />';
                }
```

The value of `this` is the current line being drawn, and `this.value` has the label.

If you run that in Chrome and hit F12 to see the Console, you can see what console.log dumps out, the full object.

If you need more differences, you could branch on that value.